# HTML: Разметка визитки

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема в создании разметки на HTML.

Пытаюсь сделать визитку, чтоб при изменении ширины браузера все поля изменялись пропорционально, а текст не выходил за пределы своего блока.

Типа так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<style>
.container { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}
 
.visitka { 
  width: 470px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_photo {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}
.visitka_name { 
  width: 45%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_phone {
  width: 45%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_s {
  width: 11%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_param1 {
  width: 28%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_param2 {
  width: 28%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.visitka_param3 {
  width: 57%;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    </style>
</head>
 
<body>
<div id="container" class="container">
<div class="visitka">
    <div class="visitka_photo">
      <h2>photo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_name">
      <h2>name</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_phone">
      <h2>phone</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_s">
      <h2>s</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_param1">
      <h2>param1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_param2">
      <h2>param2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="visitka_param3">
      <h2>param3</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос: как сделать подобную визитку?

Comment: вообще визитку лучше делать в векторных редакторах или в растровых что бы была возможность распечатать ... просто удобнее и выкладывать в html либо как SVG либо как изображение PNG

Comment: Никита Фаст, это что-то типа телефонного справочника, данные добавляются динамически

Comment: тогда на таблице, хотя если вы флекс знаете хорошо то и на флексе можно - вообще на любом способе вёрстки это можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  
}

.visitka{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid;
}

.visitka_data{
  flex-grow:1;
  border:1px solid;
}

  .data{
    display:flex;
  }
  
  .data_contacts{
    flex-grow:1;
    
  }
  
  .data_contacts div{
    border:1px solid;
  }
  
  .data_s{
    border:1px solid;
  }
  
.params_two{
  display:flex;
}

.params_two div{
  flex-grow:1;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='visitka'>
    <div class='visitka_photo'>
      <img src='' height=100 width=100>photo
    </div>
    <div class='visitka_data'>
      <div class='data'>
        <div class='data_contacts'>
         <div>
           name
         </div>
         <div>
           phone
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class='data_s'>
          div s
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class='visitka_params'>
        <div class='params_two'>
          <div>
            div param 1
          </div>
          <div>
            div param 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='params_three'>
          <div>
            div param 3
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почитайте про `flexbox`, с данной помощью очень легко верстать.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш вариант выбрал в итоге.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `table`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  table-layout: fixed;

  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}


.card-photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="card">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5" width="40%">
        <div class="card-photo">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </td>    
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" width="80%">
        <div class="card-name">
          Card Name
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="20%" height="33.33%">
        <div class="card-s">
          Card S
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" width="80%">
        <div class="card-name">
          Card Phone
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" width="50%" height="33.33%">
        <div class="card-param">
          Card Param 1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" width="50%" height="33.33%">
        <div class="card-param">
          Card Param 2
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" width="60%" height="33.33%">
        <div class="card-param">
          Card Param 3
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Вариант с `flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;

}

.align-items-stretch {
  align-items: stretch;
}


.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;

  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.card div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.card div>span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}


.card-photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.col-40 {
  width: 40%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col-60 {
  width: 60%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col-80 {
  width: 80%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col-100 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col-20 {
  width: 20%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.y-2 {
  height: 50%;
}
.y-3 {
  height: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card-photo col-40">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="card-body col-60">
      <div class="d-flex y-3 align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card-info col-80">
          <div class="y-2">
            <span>Card Name</span>
          </div>
          <div class="y-2">
            <span>Card Phone</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-s col-20">
          <span>Card S</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex y-3 align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card-param col-50">
          <span>Card Param 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-param col-50">
          <span>Card Param 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex y-3">
        <div class="card-param col-100">
          <span>Card Param 3</span>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `grid`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 2px;
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
  
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;

  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  
  grid-template-columns: 40% 20% 10% 10% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;  
}

.card-photo {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.card-name {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}

.card-phone {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}

.card-s {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
}

.card-photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.card-param-1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.card-param-2 {
  grid-column: 4 / 6;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}


.card-param-3 {
  grid-column: 2 / 6;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.card div>span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-photo">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-name">
    <span>Card Name</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-phone">
    <span>Card Phone</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-s">
    <span>Card S</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-param card-param-1">
    <span>Card Param 1</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-param card-param-2">
    <span>Card Param 2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-param card-param-3">
    <span>Card Param 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*P.S: Ответ CbIPoK2513 более красивый и компактный для `grid`.*

Вариант с `float`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;

  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  height: 300px;
}

.card div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.card div>span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.card-photo,
.card-body {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-photo img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  
}

.col-40 {
  width: 40%;
}

.col-60 {
  width: 60%;
}

.col-80 {
  width: 80%;
}

.col-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.y-2 {
  height: 50%;
}
.y-3 {
  height: 33.333%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.y-3>div {
  height: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  
  <div class="card-photo col-40">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519058082700-08a0b56da9b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eefa9be00575de989c32ab5dbe1315a9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="card-body col-60">
    <div class="y-3">
      <div class="card-info col-80">
        <div class="y-2">
          <span>Card Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="y-2">
          <span>Card Phone</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-s col-20">
        <span>Card S</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="y-3">
      <div class="card-param col-50">
        <span>Card Param 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-param col-50">
        <span>Card Param 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="y-3">
      <div class="card-param col-100">
        <span>Card Param 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox для меня показался проще.
Всё равно большое спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При помощи `display: grid` (для современных браузеров)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'photo name name name s'
    'photo tel tel tel s'
    'photo param1 param1 param2 param2'
    'photo param3 param3 param3 param3'
  ;
}

.div {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div.photo {grid-area: photo;}
.div.name {grid-area: name;}
.div.tel {grid-area: tel;}
.div.s {grid-area: s;}
.div.param1 {grid-area: param1;}
.div.param2 {grid-area: param2;}
.div.param3 {grid-area: param3;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="div photo">photo</div>
  <div class="div name">name</div>
  <div class="div tel">tel</div>
  <div class="div s">s</div>
  <div class="div param1">param1</div>
  <div class="div param2">param2</div>
  <div class="div param3">param3</div>
</div>
```

При помощи `display: inline-block;` (с поддержкой старых)

```css
.grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.grid::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}

.div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-wrap, .right-wrap {display: inline-block; float: left;}
.left-wrap {width: 40%;}
.right-wrap {width: 60%;}

.right-top-wrap, .right-middle-wrap {display: block;}
.right-top-wrap::after, .right-middle-wrap::after {content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}
 
.right-top-wrap .right-top-left-wrap, .right-top-wrap .right-top-right-wrap {display: inline-block; float: left;}
.right-top-wrap .right-top-left-wrap {width: 80%;}
.right-top-wrap .right-top-right-wrap {width: 20%;}

.right-middle-wrap .div {display: inline-block; float: left; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-wrap">
    <div class="div photo">photo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-wrap">
    <div class="right-top-wrap">
      <div class="right-top-left-wrap">
        <div class="div name">name</div>
        <div class="div tel">tel</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-top-right-wrap">
        <div class="div s">s</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-middle-wrap">
      <div class="div param1">param1</div>
      <div class="div param2">param2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div param3">param3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox для меня показался проще.
Всё равно большое спасибо за ответ.